# How is the hazard ratio in Cox proportional hazard models affected by the case sampling?

Tags: survival, survey, cox-model, design-based-inference

I'm trying to conduct survival analysis using Cox proportional hazard models, looking at a biomarker for heart disease. Age is a major risk factor, so I'm modeling the age as the time scale (counting process formulation in R package `survival`, i.e. {age_at_entry, age_at_event, event_indicator})

What is the effect of changing the sampling procedure, e.g., from a population-based study (people sampled randomly from general population) vs a case-control study, on the hazard ratio?

Can hazard ratios from different designs be meaningfully compared?

Any pointers/references welcome.

Comment: Good question -- Jerry Lawless has been producing papers and overviews of what to do on the intersection of survival and complex survey data analysis, consult with these. Unfortunately, he is pretty much the only major statistician who understands this interface. I can only claim understanding [the survey part of it](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781118594629.ch29/summary).